# Unable to parse 2D json Array and display its contents

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Am getting a 2d array from the API, am parsing the response. But am unable to get those values.

This is how am getting the response,

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
String api_uri = "http://192.168.0.106/api/something/";
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(api_uri);

httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = null;

try {
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

 inputStream = entity.getContent();
 // json is UTF-8 by default
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line + "\n");
 }
 result = sb.toString();
 Log.e("rAct", result);
} catch (Exception e) {
 // Oops
 Log.e("rActEr", e.toString());
} finally {
 try {
  if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
 } catch (Exception squish) {}
}
```

The `result` string is as follows,

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 138,
            "name": "asdasd",
            "person_image": "http://something.in:9090/photos/14/1575.jpg",
            "person_description": "bla bla blaa",
            "bla_id": 1,
            "blabal_id": 2,
            "other_id": 7,
            "category": "asd"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 257,
            "name": "asdasd",
            "person_image": "http://something.in/asd.jpg",
            "person_description": "asasdsad",
            "bla_id": 1,
            "blabal_id": 2,
            "other_id": 7,
            "category": "ASSSD"
        }
    ]
]
```

So now am trying to read the data as,

```
try {
    jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.e("testt", jsonobject.toString());
        ...
        ...
    }
}catch....
```

Am not able to get anything from that `jsonobject` 
How to get the `name`, `person_image`, `person_description` data from the result.
I tried to get them like `jsonobject.optString("name")`, but nothing returned.

With single dimension arrays, I got the response and I could read the data following the same way above.

What should I need  to modify to read the data I need?

Comment: I would recommend using 'POJO' as it make your life easier

Comment: Please take a look. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have array of arrays try to read **json array** instead of **object** inside of outer array:

```
try {
jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    jsonarrayInner = jsonarray.getJSONArray(i);
    //you can do one more loop here
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarrayInner.length(); i++) {
        jsonobject = jsonarrayInner.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.e("testt", jsonobject.toString());
    }
    ...
    ...
}
}catch....
```

Comment: Little correction in the code but guided me the right way. in the second for loop it should be `jsonobject = jsonarrayInner.getJSONObject(i);` . That change worked.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) with **POJO** in this case, it wraps your json array into `java.util.List of <YourPojo>`

```
List<MyPojo> myPojoList= new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<MyPojo>>() {
                }.getType());
```

and your pojo should be matched with your json attributes

So your class should be something like this

```
class MyPojo{
    private id;
    private String name ;
    private String person_image;
    private String person_description;
    private int bla_id;
    private int blabal_id;
    private int other_id;
    private String category;
}
```

in this way you will directly bind the json array to java Object